# Getline jump on next cin and skip the previous cin

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am trying to use getline() but after enter the 1st record cursor don't wait for 2nd country name it skip and jump on capital name. Where is my mistake. If I enter

Country: India
Capital:Delhi
 Capita: 57382 
 it take these value without any issue but cursor doesn't wait for next Country it directly jumps on Capital after entering the capita value.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct country
{
char nm[30];
char capital[30];
float income;
};

void main()
{
  country c[5];
  clrscr();
  for( int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
  {
    cout << "\n Country's name : ";
    cin.getline(c[i].nm, 30);
    cout << "\n Country's capital :";
    cin.getline(c[i].capital,30);
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n Per capita income :";
    cin >> c[i].income;
  }
```

I modified the code by adding cin.ignore();

```
  for( int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
  {
    cout << "\n Country's name : ";
    cin.getline(c[i].nm, 30);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n Country's capital :";
    cin.getline(c[i].capital,30);
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n Per capita income :";
    cin >> c[i].income;
    cin.ignore();
  }
```

But after this getline() waits for next Country but it is now waiting after each entry of Country, Capital and Capita. Means I enter

> Country:India //Press enter //waiting and I pressed enter here
>   Capital:Delhi //Press enter //waiting and I pressed enter here 
> Capita:
>   32323 //Press enter //waiting and I pressed enter here

Same for 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

Because `cin >>` doesn't consume the end-of-line character(s) following the number you typed in. These character(s) remain in the input buffer. The next time `getline()` is called, it finds the newline and assumes the user has entered an empty string by simply pressing enter.

Comment: I gussed this problem and added cin.ignore() but now a different issue arises, kindly see the edited post

Comment: @Vishal You misplaced the `ignore()` call. There should only be one, and it should be just before the *first* `getline()` call. Also, it's better to do `std::cin >> std::ws` instead of `ignore()` since you're only trying to discard whitespace.